# Finding the coordinate C.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, coordinate-systems

A triangle $A$, $B$, $C$ has the coordinates:

$A = (-1, 3)$
$B = (3, 1)$
$C = (x, y)$

$BC$ is perpendicular to $AB$. Find the coordinates of $C$

---

My attempt:

Grad of $AB$ =

$$\frac{3-1}{-1-3} = -0.5$$

Grad of $BC = 2$ ($-0.5 \times 2 = -1$ because AB and BC are perpendicular).

Equation of $BC$

$(y-1) = 2(x-3)$

$y = 2x - 5$

Equation of $AC$

$(y-3) = m(x--1)$

$y = mx+m+3$

I do not know how to proceed further. Please help me out.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf: See for example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117 or http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I have upto a certain extent mate. Is that not satisfactory?

Comment: @Bye_World I cant read what you said

Comment: I have simply ticked off the highest voted answer. It was actually my teacher's mistake of not giving all the information...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of $AC$ is $x-3y=-10$ as slope of any line is $-\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ is $x$-coordinate and $b$ is $y$-coordinate so slope is $-\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)$. $C$ is the point where $AC$ and $BC$ so meet we have two simultaneous equations $2x-y=5$ and $x-3y=-10$ solving them you get $x=5$ and $y=5$.

Comment: @Hassan This solution is correct (as far as I can see) you might want to consider accepting it. Well done Archis (+1)

Comment: Could you please explain this to me? It's quite hard to understand.

Comment: Nothing hard . I have just used slope point form to get an equation. The slope of any point is - x/y here the point is -1,3 so slope is -(-1/3)=1/3 now we have slope and point A(1,3) by slope point derive equation and the point c is intersection of BC and AC so two equations solve two unknowns. Hope I am clear on this.Thanks

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I dont understand how you made the $x - 3y = -10$ equation. Also the A coordinates are (-1, 3), not (1, 3).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

Length of $AC =$

$\sqrt{((x+1)^2 +(y-3)^2)} = \sqrt{(\mathrm{Length} \space \mathrm{of} \space (AB)^2+\mathrm{Length} \space \mathrm{of} \space (BC)^2)}\tag{1}$

because you have a right-angled triangle as $BC$ is perpendicular to $AB$

From $(1)$ $$(x+1)^2 +(y-3)^2=(3+1)^2+(1-3)^2+(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2$$
$$\implies x^2+2x+1 +y^2-6y+9=20+x^2-6x+9+y^2-2y+1$$

Comment: @HassanAlthaf  I will add also a small hint, your $C$ is found as a set of straight line.

Comment: I arrived at 8x - 20 = 8y.

Comment: After retrying I got to 8x - 4y = 20

Comment: @Hassan I'm getting something different, I'm just checking for errors

Comment: @Hassan That's what I got, which is the same $y=2x-5$

Comment: So thats the equation for the line AC?

Comment: @Hassan No it's the equation of $BC$ and unfortunately we need another unique equation to find the coordinate of C, so this method is redundant as you already obtained $y=2x-5$ from finding the gradient of $BC$ using the negative reciprocal relation. You need to find a way of obtaining another unique equation. (I'm still thinking on it).

Comment: @BLAZE I see. My friends are thinking that AC and CB are perpendicular

Comment: Could that be possible?

Comment: @Hassan I'm not sure from the given data but it's been a while since I studied coordinate geometry so maybe you should wait for a while and see if someone has a better idea, have a look at your other comments.

Comment: @BLAZE I see thanks

Comment: Blaze you are wrong at last step

Comment: @Archis I'm wrong on the whole thing not just the last step, the method gave the same equation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the gradient of line AB is $-1/2$ so the gradient of any line perpendicular to $AB$ is $2$. The line with gradient $2$ through $B = (3, 1)$ is $y = 2(x- 3)+ 1$ or $y= 2x- 5$.  All points on that line, $(x, 2x- 5)$, satisfy the conditions for C.